# Backup script using pigz ensuring CPU is used on backup server

Tags: bash, ssh, tar

Current script that backs up uses just tar with no compression.  We need to compress the backups however we need the CPU utilization to compress these backups to happen on the backup server

Current:

```
tar -cvf - . | ssh user@backupserver.com "cat > ~/vps/v16/vzpbackup_${CTID}_${HNAME}_${TIMESTAMP}.tar"
```

New:

```
tar -cvf - . | ssh user@backupserver.com "cat > ~/vps/v17/vzpbackup_${CTID}_${HNAME}_${TIMESTAMP}.tar" ; ssh user@backupserver.com "cd ~/vps/v17/; tar --use-compress-program=pigz -cvf vzpbackup_${CTID}_${HNAME}_${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz vzpbackup_${CTID}_${HNAME}_${TIMESTAMP}.tar"
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can **compress on-the-fly**:

```
tar -cvf - . | ssh user@backupserver.com "pigz > ~/vps/v17/vzpbackup_${CTID}_${HNAME}_${TIMESTAMP}.tar.gz"
```

Background: since you already send a `tar` file via the pipe, you just need to compress the piped data on the receivers side -- and you end up with a compressed tar file.

BTW, the "New" script in your question will create a compressed `tar` file that contains the uncompressed `tar` file. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: If you aren't certain that the variables in question are all `eval`-safe, it might be better to use `printf %q` to format the remote command. If you somehow ended up with `HNAME='$(rm -rf $HOME)'`, that wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: Example: `printf -v cmd 'pigz > ~/vps/v17/vzpbackup_%q_%q_%q.tar.gz' "$CTID" "$HNAME" "$TIMESTAMP"; tar -cvf - . | ssh user@backupserver.com "$cmd"`